# Show Keynote presenter view but share only slides via Zoom?

Tags: macos, keynote, screen-sharing, zoom.app

Back when I was in the office, I'd connect my MacBook Pro to a conference room's large display via HDMI cable and, using **Keynote**, show only the slides on the large display, but the presenter view (with notes) on the laptop display.

Now that I'm working from home, I have ***only*** the laptop display, but, when I give a talk via **Zoom**, I want the same thing, i.e., share *only* the slides, but *see* the presenter view on the laptop display.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to buy a [dummy plug](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B06XT1Z9TF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that acts as a tiny (but high resolution) external screen. And then you share your slides as usual. I already tried and it works well.

Of course you can use sidecar to make your iPad a second screen but this dummy plug is really easy to carry!